# itext 7 throwing Corrupted Licence key error

Tags: java, itext, hindi

I need to use Hindi and Marathi language for creating  pdfs using itext5.
loading some indian fonts(ttf) help me, but could not satisfy exact alphabet rendering.

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to its content? And what are you asking for anyways?

Comment: If you have license key errors then you must contact iText Software: https://itextpdf.com/contact. You will not get help for license keys on Stack Overflow.